# Select acces datatbase in word 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, word-2010

I have to select some rows from an access in `word 2010 in vba`, now i would like to select some things but I get an error which says my Select is wrong can you help me ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim jahr As String
Dim LfdNummer As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
jahr = TextBox1
LfdNummer = TextBox2




Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim jahr As String
Dim LfdNummer As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
jahr = TextBox1
LfdNummer = TextBox2




Set db = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase("C:\User/012886\Documents\Hendrik\trilux\EMV\Beispiel_EMV.accdb")

' Daten lesen und weiterverwenden -> über Recordset

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ITZ-EMV-Messungen")
Do While Not rs.EOF

  rs.MoveNext
Loop


 rs.Close
 db.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Also your loop seems to just move through the records of the open recordset without using any of the data..

Comment: Also, should you have that forward slash in the `db` address? `OpenDatabase("C:\User/012886\...`

Comment: Hi, I get the message: bad Syntax in From condition

Comment: What happens when you run the query `SELECT * FROM ITZ-EMV-Messungen` in Access? Does it run ok?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Try bracketing: [ITZ-EMV-Messungen] I reckon it is the dash.

Comment: Just guessing, but you seem to be mixing up late and early binding.

Comment: thank you that was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bracketing: [ITZ-EMV-Messungen] I reckon it is the dash.